# PHP: IMap search not working right - Bad message number

Tags: php, imap

I'm trying to get the last 10 emails of all emails unseen and seen - I also tried using an operator so "UNSEEN SEEN", but that doesn't seem to be working right for me as well.

This is the erro I get: Bad message number

Code:

```
private function RecentEmails(User $user)
{
    $host = 'localhost'; 
    $username = ''; 
    $password = ''; 
    // Connect to IMAP server
    $inbox = imap_open('{'.$host.':993/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX', $username, $password);

    // Check for errors
    if (!$inbox) {
        return []; // Handle error here
    } else {
        // Fetch recent emails
        $unreadEmails = imap_search($inbox, 'UNSEEN', SE_UID);
        $readEmails = imap_search($inbox, 'SEEN', SE_UID);
        $recentEmails = [];
        $emails = array_merge($unreadEmails ?: [], $readEmails ?: []);
        // Initialize array to store recent emails

        // Loop through fetched emails
        if ($emails) {
            // Limit the number of emails to fetch
            $emails = array_slice($emails, 0, 10); // Fetching only the first 10 emails

            foreach ($emails as $email) {
                $headerInfo = imap_headerinfo($inbox, $email);
                // Fetch email content
                $emailStructure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email);
                $emailContent = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email, 1); // Fetch plain text content
                
                $emailContent = utf8_decode($emailContent);
                
                // Check if the plain text content contains HTML tags
                if (strpos($emailContent, '<html>') !== false) {
                    // If HTML tags are found, treat the content as HTML
                    $recentEmails[] = [
                        'sender' => $headerInfo->fromaddress,
                        'subject' => $headerInfo->subject,
                        'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($headerInfo->MailDate)),
                        'content' => $emailContent,
                    ];
                } else {
                    // If no HTML tags are found, treat the content as plain text
                    $recentEmails[] = [
                        'sender' => $headerInfo->fromaddress,
                        'subject' => $headerInfo->subject,
                        'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($headerInfo->MailDate)),
                        'content' => nl2br(htmlspecialchars($emailContent)), // Convert plain text to HTML
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Close the IMAP connection
        imap_close($inbox);

        return $recentEmails;
    }
}
```

I've tried using an operator but that also didn't do anything. I've ran out of ideas.

Comment: Which function is reporting that error?

Comment: imap_headerinfo():
But when I go lower, all of them do

Comment: `imap_headerinfo()` expects the second argument to be a message number, not a uid. But `SE_UID` makes `imap_search()` return UIDs.

Comment: Either leave out that flag, or use `imap_msgno()` to convert the UID to a message number.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.